# Array and table

Tags: javascript, arrays

I created a table derived from an array, but I don't understand how to create a function that will overwrite an object in my array when editing on the page. You can run the worker code.

There was an idea to give all the cells id by their key and then somehow create a function for editing them, but I can't do it. **:(**

```js
window.onload = function() {
    document.querySelector('.bottom_panel > .plus').addEventListener('click', plusRow);
    document.querySelector('.bottom_panel > .minus').addEventListener('click', minusRow);

    document.querySelector('.right_panel > .plus').addEventListener('click', plusСolumn);
    document.querySelector('.right_panel > .minus').addEventListener('click', minusСolumn);
    // document.querySelectorAll('td > #0_0').addEventListener('oninput', alert);
    const tbody = document.querySelector("tbody")

    // function alert() {
    //     alert("11")
    // }

    array = [
        [1,2,3,4],
        [5,6,7,8],
        [9,10,11,12],
        [13,14,15,16]
    ];

    let N = ''
    let amountRow = array.length
    newRow = []
    let amountСolumn = array[0].length
    console.log(amountСolumn)

    function tableBuilder() {
        tbody.textContent = ""
        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            var tr = document.createElement('tr')
            for (j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                var td = document.createElement('td')
                td.innerHTML = `<input id="` + i + `_` + j + `" type="text" value="` + array[i][j] + `">`
                tr.appendChild(td)
            }
            tbody.appendChild(tr)
        }
    }
    tableBuilder()

    function plusRow() {
        for (i = 0; i < array[0].length; i++) {
            newRow.push('')
            console.log(newRow)
        }
        array.push(newRow)
        amountRow = array.length
        console.log(array)
        newRow = []
        tableBuilder()
    }

    function minusRow() {
        if (amountRow > 1) {
            array.pop()
            amountRow = array.length
            console.log(amountRow)
        } else {
            alert("Nope!")
        }
        tableBuilder()
    }

    function plusСolumn() {
        for ( i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i].push(N)
        }
        console.log(array)
        amountСolumn = array[0].length
        tableBuilder()
    }

    function minusСolumn() {
        if (amountСolumn > 1) {
            for ( i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                array[i].pop()
            }
            amountСolumn = array[0].length
            tableBuilder()
        } else {
            alert("Nope!")
        }

    }
}

// for (i = 0; i < array[0].length; i++) {
//     rowNumber = array[i]
//     for (k = 0; k < rowNumber.length; k++)
//         point = rowNumber[k]
//     console.log(rowNumber[k])
//     tbody.innerHTML += `<div>` + point + `</div>`
// }
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 20vh 0 0 0;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 35px;
    border: black 1px solid;
}

td:hover, input:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: silver;
}

td:hover input {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: silver;
}

input {
    margin: 1px 0 0 0;
    border: none;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
}

input:focus {
    border: 1px #000 solid;
    outline:none;
    background: none !important;
}

button {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 35px;
    height: 20px;
}

.minus {
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.bottom_panel {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

.right_panel {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: -3% 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Spreadsheet</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="table">
        <table>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="bottom_panel">
            <button class="plus">+</button>
            <button class="minus">-</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right_panel">
        <button class="plus">+</button>
        <button class="minus">-</button>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<!--<tr>-->
<!--    <td><input class="input" type="text" value="1" readonly="true" ondblclick="this.readOnly='';"></td>-->
<!--    <td><input type="text" value="2"></td>-->
<!--    <td><input class="input" type="text" value="3"></td>-->
<!--</tr>-->
```

Comment: Check out [`.value`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp)

Comment: Why are you trying to edit the array instead of editing the DOM ?  And have you researched DOM navigation?  There are a *ton* of questions/answers on this site about how to find and edit an element or text in a table cell.

Comment: @devlincarnate Because then I will need to save the table to LocalStorage

Comment: @devlincarnate I need to save the table to LocalStorage. Therefore, I think it would be more appropriate to edit the array and then save it.

Comment: Then we need to understand where you're new value(s) come from.  Please edit your question, remove the unnecessary code that doesn't pertain to your specific question (like the CSS, etc), and add in the part that shows us how you get "new" values.

Comment: Also, we need to see how you're saving to Local Storage.  It's still not making sense why you would update the array.  The array is used to render the DOM.  If a user is then editing and element in the DOM, you would just save that edit to Local Storage.  Changing the array doesn't make sense.  Unless you're doing something different?  That's why we need to see how you're saving to Local Storage.  We need to understand exactly what it is you're doing and how you want it to work.